# Ftp recv() command creating blank files when the file is not found

Tags: vba, ftp, windows-shell

I am using a simple recv(/get) command to get a bunch of files from a remote
mainframe server. I first create a text file with the servername, username, pwd
and the list of files I want transferred, then I use a .bat file with `ftp
-s:<created text file.txt>` in the command prompt, which is launched using the
shell command from VBA.

Now my problem is, I do not know which of the list of files exist and which
don't. In those cases where a file is not found, I do not want any file to be
created. But currently a blank file of 0KB is being created. These are all csv
files that I am trying to transfer. When I try the same process on another
system, it seems to work fine, i.e it does not create any file if one does not
exist for transferring. This is the basic function I want to perform, if file
exists then, transfer, else let be it.

I am probably missing some very simple option, I have tried searching online
for possible solutions but to no avail, I hope the information I have provided
is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I believe I resolved it by using `mget` instead of `get`. You will need to enter `prompt` in your text file to turn interactive mode off. Otherwise, you will get confirmation prompts when running the script.